# Should you delete your own off-topic, answerless questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, unanswered-questions

I unfortunately asked [a very off-topic question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309186/can-you-help-me-improving-my-questions-on-software-engineering) here yesterday.
I requested to move it to the appropriate meta site by flagging for moderator attention, but got no response. Eventually the question was (rightly so) put on-hold as off-topic, and but (naturally) kept accumulating downvotes.

So, what should I do with the question?

Should I preserve it in the off-chance that another user tries to post a similar (off-topic) question here, so he might see it and realize that this is the wrong place for the question?

Or should I put it out of its misery and delete it? (I seem to recall that deleting questions is frowned upon, and penalized by the systems that determine if you are permitted to ask questions in the first place.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, thank you for realizing your mistake. Flags can take a while to be handled here, so you're better off deleting this question and repost it yourself on [Software Engineering Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Even if you don't delete it, [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) will kick after 9 days and delete the question, so the chance that another user sees it is highly unlikely. For the question ban, it doesn't seem to matter if you self-delete it or if Roomba does it; furthermore, it's hard to get question banned on Meta Stack Exchange, the rules are more forgiving than on main sites.

Comment: @rene Too late. It will now be preserved for eternity in the revision history ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take the old girl behind the shed now...